# Merge multiple rows into one row in sql query?

Tags: sql-server

In a table called `USERACCOUNT`, records are as given below,

```
User Name   |  Gmail   |  Yahoo  | Hotmail
Sankar      |   X      |  NULL   |  NULL
Aravinth    |   NULL   |   X     |  NULL
Pavithran   |   NULL   |  NULL   |  X
```

My excepted result is:

```
User Name   |  Gmail   |  Yahoo  | Hotmail
Sankar      |   X      |  X      |  X
```

Please help me regarding this,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Mysql or sqlserver ?

Comment: Question is not clear what would be the result for user Aravinth    and pavithrana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to check each column is it `NULL` or not with the help of `ISNULL`

```
declare @temp table 
(
name nvarchar(11),
gmail nvarchar(11),
yahoo nvarchar(11),
hotmail nvarchar(11))

insert into @temp values ('snkar'   ,'X' ,  NULL,  NULL)
insert into @temp values ('avinth' ,NULL, 'Y'  ,  NULL)
insert into @temp values ('vithran',NULL,NULL  ,'Z'  )

select * from @temp

select 
name,isnull(gmail,isnull(yahoo,hotmail)) gmail,
isnull(yahoo,isnull(gmail,hotmail)) yahoo,
isnull(hotmail,isnull(gmail,yahoo)) hotmail    
from @temp
```

and if we have multiple rows with same name like that and we have to filter data same as then this method will helpful

```
insert into @temp values ('snkar'   ,'X' ,  NULL,  NULL)
insert into @temp values ('snkar' ,NULL, 'X'  ,  NULL)
insert into @temp values ('snkar',NULL,NULL  ,'X'    )

select name,max(gmail) gmail,max(yahoo) yahoo,max(hotmail) hotmail
from @temp
group by name
```

Comment: @SankarRamalingam please put your second problem also in Q so it will helpful for future upcoming user

Answer (score 0):

[COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349(v=SQL.120).aspx) is more suitable

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
    name nvarchar(11),
    gmail nvarchar(11),
    yahoo nvarchar(11),
    hotmail nvarchar(11)
)

INSERT INTO @temp VALUES ('snkar'   ,'X' ,  NULL,  NULL)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES ('avinth' ,NULL, 'Y'  ,  NULL)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES ('vithran',NULL,NULL  ,'Z'  )

SELECT * 
FROM @temp

SELECT 
name, COALESCE(gmail,yahoo,hotmail) gmail,
COALESCE(yahoo,gmail,hotmail) yahoo,
COALESCE(hotmail,gmail,yahoo) hotmail    
FROM @temp
```